# Flex install badge inside a Flex Application?

Tags: apache-flex, installation, air, badge

I have created a flex SWF file for my web page. I also have a AIR application.

Is it possible to use the install badge that is available for HTML pages inside my Flex web application? Or any alternative ideas / suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, but not using the badge.swf this just used the air.swf file from Adobe does certain checks.

[Installing & Launching AIR applications from FLEX Web Application](http://www.medoix.com.au/2009/11/06/install-launch-air-application-from-flex-web-page/)

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it but I guess you just have to load the badge (SWF file) within your Flex app?

Comment: i have thought about that, but i am still unsure how you would pass the variables to the SWF i.e the AIR application path and the image path etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SWFLoader, and pass the variables you need by appending them to the URL.

See http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=175951